# How can I stretch a Grid or Canvas to fill the contents of a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say in an example like this, I would like the Grid to fill the entire Button with Red.

```
<Button Margin="2">
    <Grid x:Name="adGrid" Background="Red">                             
        <StackPanel>                                    
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=adGrid}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="x"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=adGrid}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

I just end up with this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `Grid` is not covering the entire `Button`. If you want the entire `Button` to be `red` either set the `background` color of `button` to red or stretch the `grid` to cover rest of the `button`

Either do

```
<Button Margin="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

or

```
<Button Margin="2" Background="Red">
        ...
</Button>
```